# jQuery - detect cut / paste with textarea auto-expand function

Tags: jquery

I have a function that auto-expands the `textarea` `width` and `height` however when I `cut` or `paste` the textarea value, the auto-expand function doesn't fire. How do I bind the resize function to detect when I paste in or cut away text?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $inputs = $(".expandable");

  function resizeForText(text) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!text.trim()) {
      text = $this.attr("placeholder").trim();
    }
    var $span = $this.parent().find("span");
    $span.text(text);
    var $inputSize = $span.outerWidth(true);
    $this.css("width", $inputSize);
  }

  $inputs.find("textarea").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which && e.charCode) {
      var c = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode | e.charCode);
      var $this = $(this);
      resizeForText.call($this, $this.val() + c);
    }
  });

  // Backspace event only fires for keyup
  $inputs.find("textarea").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) {
      resizeForText.call($(this), $(this).val());
    }
  });

  $inputs.find("textarea").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    resizeForText.call($this, $this.val());
  });
  var textarea = $("textarea");
  textarea.on("input", function() {
    $(this).css("height", ""); //reset the height
    $(this).css("height", Math.min($(this).prop("scrollHeight")));
  });
});
```

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: .9rem;
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.expandable span {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 12px;
}

.measure {
  width: 200px;
  background: #ececec;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="measure">200px</div>
<div class="expandable">
  <textarea type="text" rows="1" class="textarea" placeholder="Placeholder" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe these will be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/cut_event and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event

Comment: @KyleUnderhill please check my answer if its works as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have rewritten code in `jQuery` plugin structure.

#### Example 1

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.expandable = function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $span = $this.find('span');

    function resizeForText(text) {
      var $input = $(this);
      if (!text.trim()) {
        text = $input.attr("placeholder").trim();
      }

      $span.text(text);

      var $inputWidth = $span.outerWidth(true);
      $input.css("width", $inputWidth);

      $input.css("height", ""); // reset the height
      if (text != "Placeholder") {
        $input.css("height", Math.min($input.prop("scrollHeight")));
      }
    }

    this.each(function() {
      var $textarea = $this.find('textarea');

      $textarea.on('input', function(e) {
        resizeForText.call($textarea, $textarea.val());
      });

      // Backspace event only fires for keyup
      $textarea.keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) {
          resizeForText.call($textarea, $textarea.val());
        }
      });

      resizeForText.call($textarea, $textarea.val());
    });
  }
}(jQuery))

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".expandable").expandable();
});
```

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: .9rem;
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.expandable span {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 12px;
}

.measure {
  width: 200px;
  background: #ececec;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="measure">200px</div>
<div class="expandable">
  <textarea type="text" rows="1" class="textarea" placeholder="Placeholder" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

#### Example 2

Here you can pass how many rows you want it to appear after text
Single row height is `calculated` through textarea `font-size`

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.expandable = function(options) {
    $rowsAfterText = (options && options.hasOwnProperty('rowsAfterText')) ? options.rowsAfterText : 1;

    $this = $(this);
    $span = $this.find('span');
    $single_row_height = 0;
    $max_width = 0;

    function calculateHeight(suggestedHeight) {
      if ($rowsAfterText == 0) {
        return suggestedHeight - (($single_row_height - 4) * 3);
      } else if ($rowsAfterText == 1) {
        return suggestedHeight - $single_row_height;
      } else if ($rowsAfterText == 2) {
        return suggestedHeight;
      }
      return suggestedHeight + ($single_row_height * ($rowsAfterText - 2));
    }

    function calculateWidth(suggestedWidth, _strlen) {
      if (suggestedWidth < $max_width) {
        var width = suggestedWidth + _strlen;
        if (width < $max_width) return width;
        return $max_width;
      }
      return suggestedWidth;
    }

    function resizeForText(text) {
      var $input = $(this);
      if (!text.trim()) {
        text = $input.attr("placeholder").trim();
      }

      $span.text(text);

      var $inputWidth = $span.outerWidth(true);
      if (text != "Placeholder") {
        $inputWidth = calculateWidth($inputWidth, text.length);
      }
      $input.css("width", $inputWidth);

      $input.css("height", ""); // reset the height
      if (text != "Placeholder") {
        $input.css("height", calculateHeight(Math.min($input.prop("scrollHeight"))));
      }
    }

    this.each(function() {
      var $textarea = $this.find('textarea');
      $single_row_height = parseInt($textarea.css('font-size'));
      $max_width = parseInt($textarea.css('max-width')) || parseInt($textarea.css('width'));

      $textarea.on('input', function(e) {
        resizeForText.call($textarea, $textarea.val());
      });

      // Backspace event only fires for keyup
      $textarea.keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) {
          resizeForText.call($textarea, $textarea.val());
        }
      });

      resizeForText.call($textarea, $textarea.val());
    });
  }
}(jQuery))

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".expandable").expandable({
    rowsAfterText: 0
  });
});
```

```css
textarea {
  font-size: 14px;
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: .9rem;
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.expandable span {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 12px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.measure {
  width: 200px;
  background: #ececec;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="measure">200px</div>
<div class="expandable">
  <textarea type="text" rows="1" class="textarea" placeholder="Placeholder" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Any idea how to prevent the height of the textarea from changing on keyup the way it does? I'm not sure where in the code this happens but want the height to only increase proportionately to the number of rows. The issue is with the padding of the textarea.

Comment: @KyleUnderhill please check updated answer still any doubt please let me know

Comment: Thanks for the update. What I meant was that there shouldn't ever be any whitespace on the textarea. In other words the height of the textarea should always match the height of the input text (i.e wrap around it). Currently it looks like additional rows have been calculated for the height on keyup when it should remain the height of one row until it wraps the the height of the textarea expands to accommodate.

Comment: @KyleUnderhill you can simply pass `rowsAfterText` option to 0 then it will only expands when text cannot fits.

Comment: I noticed the text is wrapping before the max width is reached. How do we get it so the text only wraps when the max-width is reached?

Comment: @KyleUnderhill i have fixed width issue, I noticed it before but though maybe it was required that way